# How to limit the link open only once in new tab?

Tags: html

In my code, after click on a link I'm open a pdf file in new tab, But after second click if that file is already open then instead of open in new tab I want to redirect to open tab of that file.

My code:

```
<span style="margin-left:10%;"><a href="image/Eng_Pamphlet.pdf" target="_blank">Broucher</a></span>'
```

As shown in above tab I'm set the target attribute "_blank", So it opens the link always in new tab. But I want after first time it redirect to first open tab only.

Answer (score 6):

Use `target="_new"` instead. This will open the link in the same tab

Edit:

`_new` is not really the best way to do this, as noted in the comment below by Chankey. You can just create a 'custom' value for the `target` attribute that will allow the link to only open in a specific tab.

http://jsfiddle.net/GTr7L/ -> example

Comment: There is no such keyword as `_new` in HTML5, and not in HTML4 (and consequently XHTML) either. That means, that there will be no consistent behaviour whatsoever if you use this as a value for the target attribute.

Comment: Why this doenot work for facebook. I tried this:
    <p><a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_new">Visit facebook!</a></p>

Comment: As described in the comment above by Chankey, this is probably not the best way but here is a Fiddle with a better way that works http://jsfiddle.net/GTr7L/ your HTML was invalid, which was probably the thing breaking it

Answer (score 5):

just assign a custom name to your target tab, so all the links will be redirected to your custom tab

```
<span style="margin-left:10%;"><a href="image/Eng_Pamphlet.pdf" target="myPDFTabAndEveryTimeThisOne">Broucher</a></span>'
```

(if you use "_new" another standard "_new" link will overwrite your pdf tab).