# .NET Web Application Set Link to Open Only One New Tab in IE11

Tags: html, vb.net, hyperlink, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a web application (IIS) targeting .NET 4.0 using Visual Studio 2015.

I have a link to a third party that I want to open in a new tab.  However, if the user has already clicked it and opened the new tab and then they click the link again I don't want it to open yet another tab - it should use the tab it opened the first time they clicked.

I created a custom target name, as per this question:

[How to limit the link open only once in new tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859677/how-to-limit-the-link-open-only-once-in-new-tab)

This works beautifully in Chrome, Firefox, and even Edge.  However, it does not work in Internet Explorer - every click opens yet another tab, the same as setting the target to _blank

Unfortunately we are required to support IE11.  Is there a way to get this to work in IE11?

EDIT:  link code working in all but IE11

```
<a target="ThirdPartyLink" linkinfo="../THIRDPARTY/THIRDPARTYSSO.ASPX" href="#">Facility</a>
```

Comment: I try to check the link and try to test the code from the answer and find that it opens a new tab every time in any browser. If you are sure that your code is working than I suggest you to post your exact code in your question. I will again try to test it on my side. Other solution is to disable the link once user click on it. So user will not be able to open new tab using that link.

Comment: Indeed, the Fiddle example in that answer does not work but when I added a custom target on my own code it did work for everything but IE11.  I've added the link code to my question.  When I run the above code in JSFiddle it works correctly.

Comment: I made a test with your code and looks like it is working fine in IE 11. Here is my testing result. https://imgur.com/a/WL4LOK4 You can see that I click the link many times but it only opens single tab. You can try to again check on your side and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: Yes, it works in IE11 if the destination URL has nothing on the page.  But if there are any controls it opens a new tab each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work in IE11 by adding the third-party URL to my Trusted Sites.